# multiword parameter in jquery not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, url, parameters

this is going something weird. Below is my jquery code --

```
$("#results" ).load("fetch_pages8.php?dfrom="+dfrom+"&dto="+dto+"&os="+os); //load initial records

//executes code below when user click on pagination links
$("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
    var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages8.php?dfrom="+dfrom+"&dto="+dto+"&os="+os,{"page":page}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
        $(".loading-div").hide(); //once done, hide loading element
    });                   
});
```

Here `os = "Unknown OS Type"`

Now the problem is in `fetch_pages8.php` where it's not getting the value of the`os` parameter.
For testing when O sent `os = "Android"` then everything is working as expected. 
Then I understood that the problem is with multiple word parameters.

Comment: use underscode when passing multiword param instead of space.

Comment: Could you show your complete code?

Comment: you probably need to URL-encode the parameter values before you attach them to the URL.

Comment: Fixed code formatting as well as minor grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode your parameters as jQuery searches for whitespace to understand if you want to load some specific DOM element from response (e.g. `.load('example.com #someDiv .contents')`

To encode use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
$("#results" ).load(
    "fetch_pages8.php?dfrom="+encodeURIComponent(dfrom)+"&dto="+encodeURIComponent(dto)+"&os="+encodeURIComponent(os)
)
```

Or use [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to encode whole URI:

```
$("#results" ).load(encodeURI("fetch_pages8.php?dfrom="+dfrom+"&dto="+dto+"&os="+os))
```